# Questions about Page Attribute Table (PAT)

Tags: operating-system, kernel, paging

I'm trying to write a kernel, and some of the memory need to be uncacheable.

I read the Intel document for PAT, and understand the following:

1.There is "IA32_PAT MSR" register holding 8 slot like the following:

[image]

2. Each of the lower 3 bit hold a figure that can represent the following caching type:

[image]

3. By manipulating PAT,PWD,PCD bit on each paging tables, I can select the slot I would like to use and decide the caching type.
4. For any structure including CR3 pointing to a page structure (paging table), it only use PWD,PCD to select caching type. In which only the first 4 entries in "IA32_PAT MSR" can be selected. Furthermore, it only effect the caching of the page structure it pointed to (such as CR3 point to a PML4E table, it only determine the caching type of the PML4E table)
5. For any structure that pointing to a physical page, it use PAT, PWD, PCD to select all 8 entries in "IA32_PAT MSR"

---

So I would like to ask:

1. If the previews understanding are OK
2. Do I need to enable it, or it is automatically enabled if supported.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Intel's manual](http://www.nj7p.org/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/243690-001.pdf) about the Page Attribute Table (PAT) :

How to detect PAT :

```
The page attribute table (PAT) feature is detected by an operating system through the use of the
CPUID instruction. Specifically, the operating system executes the CPUID instruction with the
value 1 in the EAX register, and then determines support for the feature by inspecting bit 16 of
the EDX register return value.
```

How to enable PAT :

```
Note that there is not a separate flag or control bit in any of the control registers that enables the
use of this feature. The PAT is always enabled on all processors that support it, and the table
lookup always occurs whenever paging is enabled and for all paging modes (e.g., PSE, PAE).
```